# Read raw data from USBPcap library

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++

I am using [USBPcap](https://github.com/desowin/usbpcap/tree/master/USBPcapCMD) to capture transferred data between USB device drive and OS but it will save the data in `.pcap` file which just can be read by Wireshark it self. I go into USBPcap source code but because i don't know anything about Windows API i can't understand the source, Just found this file while debugging :

https://github.com/desowin/usbpcap/blob/master/USBPcapCMD/thread.c#L177

I need the raw data, Not `.pcap` coded file. How i could get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.pcap` file format is simple, the easiest solution is to parse it yourself or use an existing library: https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat

USBPcap uses the format above: https://github.com/desowin/usbpcap/blob/37a8e3cf12234df96a7e101eec336085dbb3e4c7/USBPcapDriver/include/USBPcap.h#L63

The file header is:

```
typedef struct pcap_hdr_s {
    UINT32 magic_number;   /* magic number */
    UINT16 version_major;  /* major version number */
    UINT16 version_minor;  /* minor version number */
    INT32  thiszone;       /* GMT to local correction */
    UINT32 sigfigs;        /* accuracy of timestamps */
    UINT32 snaplen;        /* max length of captured packets, in octets */
    UINT32 network;        /* data link type */
} pcap_hdr_t;
```

Each packet has the format:

```
typedef struct pcaprec_hdr_s {
    UINT32 ts_sec;         /* timestamp seconds */
    UINT32 ts_usec;        /* timestamp microseconds */
    UINT32 incl_len;       /* number of octets of packet saved in file */
    UINT32 orig_len;       /* actual length of packet */
} pcaprec_hdr_t;
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond, I look at source where data will be write in the file, But i could not found any footprint of those headers. [this](https://github.com/desowin/usbpcap/blob/37a8e3cf12234df96a7e101eec336085dbb3e4c7/USBPcapCMD/thread.c#L110) is where write it happens.

Comment: You linked where write to output file (or pipe) happens. USBPcapCMD is essentially a userspace helper interface to the driver. The actual captured pcap packets are generated in USBPcapDriver. USBPcapCMD simply forwards the data read from USBPcapDriver and writes it to output. It does not even check the packet boundaries - it just copies the bytes.